# Declaring new class() beginning of class

Tags: php

I'm working on a Content Management System for My wife who wants to create a website, and I have a way I've always done things within the past, but I want to deliver better coding procedures, so this is my dilemma.

This is Code I've used in the past that I know works.

```
class accounts {
    public function CheckAccountLogin() {
        global $db;
        $query = <<<SQL
        SELECT id,gaToken
        FROM accounts
        WHERE password_hash = :hashedpw
SQL;
        $resource = $db->sitedb->prepare( $query );
        try {
            $resource->execute( array (
            ':hashedpw' => sha1($_POST['user-name'].':'.$_POST['user-pass']),
            ));
            if($resource->rowCount() == 0 ) { echo false;}
            else { 
            foreach($resource as $row) { 
            $this->authkey = $row['gaToken'];
            if($this->authkey == "") {
                self::SetSession();
                }
                else {
                    self::CheckAuth();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage(); 
        }

    }
}
```

Now every function would need `global $db` at the start of the function in order to utilize `$db->sitedb` or else we would have an error thrown our way, so what I want to do instead is

```
class accounts {
    public $db = new db();
    public function CheckAccountLogin() {
        $query = <<<SQL
        SELECT id,gaToken
        FROM accounts
        WHERE password_hash = :hashedpw
SQL;
        $resource = $this->sitedb->prepare( $query );
        try {
            $resource->execute( array (
            ':hashedpw' => sha1($_POST['user-name'].':'.$_POST['user-pass']),
            ));
            if($resource->rowCount() == 0 ) { echo false;}
            else { 
            foreach($resource as $row) { 
            $this->authkey = $row['gaToken'];
            if($this->authkey == "") {
                self::SetSession();
                }
                else {
                    self::CheckAuth();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage(); 
        }

    }
}
```

This way within all my new functions I'm able to simply declare `$this->sitedb` whenever I need to connect to the database. With the above code I'm given
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in /var/www/html/functions.d/accounts.class.php on line 3`. I know where the issue is, I'm just looking for a cleaner way than my first code block. Any help in getting this to work correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: use dependency injection or make a singleton model class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize a variable there unless it can be evaluated at compile time. So you can't call `new` there. See the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). Do it in the constructor.

```
class accounts {
    public $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new db();
    }
}
```

Comment: That actually works great, I never thought about utilizing construct in each class, I'm thinking I can use it to clean up a lot of what I had. For instance a construct function that's automatically included as a subclass and instantiates all classes. Thanks.

Comment: Probably more wise to use a protected variable for something like databases, so it can't be modified outside the class

Comment: Good point. I tried to make my code as similar to the original example as possible so it would be easy to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global class `DbConnect` where you statically define the database object db and connect it to your database, in this way you will keep a single database connection object throughout your application.

Include this class at the beginning before any code, then you can access this object anywhere through `::` operator in any class that follows.